# Is every compact subset of $\Bbb{R}$ the support of some Borel measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have tried to prove the exercise 2.12 in Rudin's RCA:

> **12** Show that every compact subset of $\Bbb{R}$ is the support of a Borel measure.

For perfect (i.e. no isolated point) compact $K$ with non-zero Lebesgue measure, we just take the Lebesgue measure. However I struck on the general case.

My attempt is as follows: For every compact $K$, we can find a decreasing sequence of open set $\langle W_n\rangle_n$ s.t. $\bigcap_n W_n =K$ and $m(W_n-K)<1/n$. Find a continuous function $h_n$ s.t.

1. $h_n(x) = 1$ for $x\in K$ and
2. $h_n(x) = 0$ outside of $V_n$.

(such function exists by Urysohn's lemma.) For continuous function $f$ with compact support define
$$\Lambda f = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\int_\Bbb{R} fh_ndm}{\int_\Bbb{R} h_ndm}.$$

I can not certain that the $\Lambda$ is well-defined. But if it is well-defined, then it gives an regular Borel measure (by Riesz representation theorem) $\mu$ s.t. $\mu(K)=1$. I guess that the $\mu$ has a support $K$ but I don't know how to get it. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but doesn't it also work to use the counting measure?
Take the cardinality of the intersection of a Borel set with the given compact set $K$.

Using this definition of support of a measure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(measure_theory)

Comment: @bryanj I think it works, and your idea seems similar to that of Robert Israel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: try a sum of point masses for a countable dense subset.

Comment: For those who are looking for a complete proof: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4148692/every-compact-subset-of-mathbb-r1-is-the-support-of-a-borel-measure)