# Every compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is the support of a Borel measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This is an exercise from Rudin's Real and Complex analysis pg 58. I have been stuck as to

1. What the support of a measure even is. Originally Rudin defines it on a compact Hausdorff space, but since $\mathbb{R}$ is only locally compact how does this definition extend.
2. How to define a positive linear functional $\Lambda$ that would help generate this measure?

---

I have already seen the other post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1507443/is-every-compact-subset-of-bbbr-the-support-of-some-borel-measure) about the same question and not only is the poster much farther than me the hint doesn't really give me any insights as to how to solve it.

Comment: The measure is not defined on $\mathbb R;$ it's defined on a compact subset of $\mathbb R.$