# Every compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is the support of a Borel measure. Another Solution.

Tags: real-analysis

This question is already discussed in Math Stack: [Is every compact subset of $\Bbb{R}$ the support of some Borel measure?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1507443/is-every-compact-subset-of-bbbr-the-support-of-some-borel-measure)

But my question is not above.

I want to ask that why my solution is not correct.

For given compact set $K$, let measure $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure restricted on $K$. Then why $\mu$ doesn't satisfy given condtions?

Comment: If $K$ is a Lebesgue null set, then what is $\mu$?

Comment: Or: Say $K = [0,1] \cup\{2\}$ and $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure restricted to $K$. Then the support of $\mu$ is just $[0,1]$.